# Get last_modified_date from a group of date of each target

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I've a table in oracle database:

```
 Transaction_ID  Target     Status  Last_modified_date

   80913570      8536349      1     2018-10-03 03:40:36.0
   80913540      8860342      1     2018-09-28 08:45:32.0
   80913541      9135368      1     2018-09-28 08:45:42.0
   80913532      8860342      1     2018-09-28 08:12:52.0
   80913624      9256309      1     2018-10-05 01:25:06.0
   80913573      9256309      0     2018-10-03 07:18:35.0
   80913574      9256309      0     2018-10-03 07:21:26.0
   80913576      9256309      1     2018-10-03 07:28:36.0
   80913613      5429179      0     2018-10-08 05:45:00.0
   80913614      5429179      1     2018-10-04 06:48:06.0
```

In this table, I want most recent modified dates of all **Target**. As some **Targets** have single record while others are with multiple modified dates.

I tried following query:

```
select max(last_modified_date) from demoTable where target in (select distinct target from demoTable);
```

But, is getting only one value among all Targets due to in condition while I want values of to all Targets.

*PL/SQL too can be used to achieve the results. But I'm new to the industry, I don't know exactly how to do it.

Comment: share your sample data and expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use group by

```
select target,max(last_modified_date) from demoTable 
group by target
```

Answer (score 1):

use co-related sub-query, As you need each target recent date so you can choose any of the method from below two

```
select t.* from demoTable t     
where t.Last_modified_date in
   ( select max(Last_modified_date) from demoTable t1
           where t1.Target=t.Target
   )
```

Or use `row_number` window function

```
select  Transaction_ID ,Target , Status, Last_modified_date from
(
 select Transaction_ID ,Target , Status, Last_modified_date , row_number() over(partition by target order by Last_modified_date desc) as rn from demoTable
) t where t.rn=1
```

Comment: Thank u! but answer by "fa09" was easy to understand and meets my need...